# Can I use T-Money on AREX Express from Seoul Station to Incheon Airport?

Tags: payment-cards, south-korea, seoul

I want to go back to Incheon from Seoul Station. When I came here, I used a bus from Incheon to Gangnam Station, but now I want to use [AREX Express to return to the airport](http://asiaenglish.visitkorea.or.kr/ena/GK/GK_EN_2_2_4.jsp).

Can I purchase the express ticket using my T-Money? It is the direct express line, not the all-stop train, which you can get on using T-Money.

Alternatively, if T-Money is not available, can I still buy the ticket using a credit card (Amex)?

Comment: For your information, I already finished my return trip by getting on the all-stop train in case T-Money is unavailable to the direct line, but I still want to know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I just arrived in Seoul and found out that no, you cannot use T-money for express AREX train from Incheon airport to Seoul station, where as you can use T-money for local AREX train from ICN to Seoul.  So we had to take the local AREX train from Incheon airport to Seoul station.  Same route, except local AREX train stops at every stop and takes roughly 1 hour 20 minutes vs 45 minutes for express AREX train.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRP/TP_ENG_2_1.jsp (updated recently):

- Express train ticket can be purchased by credit card or cash (but not T-Money);
- All stop train ticket can be "purchased" by cash or T-money (but not credit card)

Comment: Well, I read the page but it doesn't assert that Express train ticket can't be purchased by T-Money; it does mention nothing on T-Money, which may or may not be used there.

Comment: It says "Payment method: Credit card and cash both accepted" for AREX, and lists T-Money at "Transportation card information" for "all stop train" down there. Thus they know about T-Money, and didn't list it there as accepted. Thus the only reasonable conclusion is that T-Money is not accepted for payment for AREX, together with postal money orders, traveler checks and gold jewelry (which is also not listed as "not accepted").

Answer (score 2):

I just finished my trip and I couldn’t use T money card for express train, so I use cash. However, recharge Tmoney card only accept cash.

The other way to purchase express train ticket by using credit card is buying from third parties. I used KKday which is cheaper than counter. You just need to be aware of that you only can exchange the ticket of the day if you buy a coupon on KKday

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294197-i8161-k4994104-o10-Can_T_money_card_be_used_for_AREX_trains-Seoul.html

According to reply #17 of this tripadvisor query, it is possible to do so but you have to speak to an agent and have them deduct the fare from your T-money card.